# Switching on SqlException.Number in Powershell

Tags: powershell, sqlexception

I have this catch block in my Powershell script.

```
catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException]
{
   Write-Host "$_"
   Exit 2
}
```

I would really like to be able to switch on the error number.
I know atleast in C# there's a property on the SqlException called number. Isn't that also true for Powershell?

If the property is there, how do I access it?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access it in your `catch` block using:

```
$_.Exception.Number
```

i.e.

```
catch [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException]
{
   Write-Host $_.Exception.Number
   Exit 2
}
```